# Oracle Query with multiple records

Tags: oracle

I have a students table that has multiple columns, however, I'm only interested in the re-enrollment column and the exitcode column. When a student graduates they are given a code of 'W21', when they are promoted to the next graded they are given a code of 'P'. They will also have a corresponding record in the re-enrollment column that contains the date of registration.

I need to find all students with an exitcode of 'W21' and that have also been in the District for the last four years. So a student with a code of 'W21' that has only been in the District for 3 years wouldn't be pulled.

```
Lisa, Simpson   240011111111        20-AUG-07   W10
Lisa, Simpson   240011111111        18-AUG-08   W10
Lisa, Simpson   240011111111        18-AUG-09   W21
Bart, Simpson   240022222222        07-AUG-00   W10
Bart, Simpson   240022222222        09-AUG-01   W10
Bart, Simpson   240022222222        08-AUG-02   W10
Bart, Simpson   240022222222        11-AUG-03   W10
Bart, Simpson   240022222222        09-AUG-04   W10
Bart, Simpson   240022222222        08-AUG-05   W10
Bart, Simpson   240022222222        14-AUG-06   W10
Bart, Simpson   240022222222        20-AUG-07   W10
Bart, Simpson   240022222222        18-AUG-08   W10
Bart, Simpson   240022222222        18-AUG-09   W21
Homer, Simpson  240000333333        07-AUG-00   W10
Homer, Simpson  240000333333        09-AUG-01   W10
Homer, Simpson  240000333333        08-AUG-02   W10
Homer, Simpson  240000333333        11-AUG-03   W10
Homer, Simpson  240000333333        09-AUG-04   W10
Homer, Simpson  240000333333        08-AUG-05   W10
Homer, Simpson  240000333333        14-AUG-06   W10
Homer, Simpson  240000333333        20-AUG-07   W10
Homer, Simpson  240000333333        18-AUG-08   W10
Homer, Simpson  240000333333        18-AUG-09   NS
Homer, Simpson  240000333333        21-AUG-09   W21
```

Basically I would need only to pull Bart and Homer because they where in the district the four years before they graduated. Lisa wouldn't be pulled.

I'm stumped how to accomplish this and any help would be great.

Thanks

Comment: Help us help you - please share some sample data and the result you'd like to get for it.

Comment: Please show a [mcve], and also maybe read [ask] to get better response.  Thanks.

Comment: What is the definition of "has been in the District for the last four years"? Do they need to have several rows in the table, with a re-enrolment date in each of the years 2013, 2014, 2015 and 2016? (Or does RE-enrolment mean they have been there for a year already, and you check for reenrollment in 2014, 2015 and 2016?) Is it enough to find at least ONE reenrollment date that is far enough into the past, such as "on or before Sept. 1, 2013" or something of the sort? Writing a query is easy, as long as the requirement is crystal clear.

Comment: They would have one row per year. So, each entry would need at least 4 entries in this table.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, it is not going to be very fast, but it will work:

```
select *
  from studentrecords
 where     exitcode = 'W21'
       and studentid in (select studentid
                           from studentrecords
                          where exitcode = 'W21'
                         intersect
                           select studentid
                             from studentrecords
                            where enrollmentyear >= :fouryearsago
                         group by studentid
                           having count (*) >= 4)
```

Comment: The speed on this isn't very bad, speed isn't an issue anyway. However, the last subquery is a problem I need to make sure that each student has been in the District the last 4 years.

Comment: For example, if Bart graduated in 2015 I would to verify that his last 4 years have been in the District. He could have went to elementary school in the District and transferred out only to come back on his last year of school. If this was the case I wouldn't want him in my data.

Comment: Just add a where clause in the second part of the subquery limiting records to 4 years old or less (the count of the records for the last 4 years is 4)

Comment: Modified query to meet last 4 years requirement

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Comment: No problem, please do not forget to upvote and accept the answer if it solved your problem

Answer (score 0):

A group by with a having clause should suffice for this. Truncating the dates to year and counting distinct should solve for the number of years.

```
select
   e.student, e.sid, count(distinct trunc(dated,'YYYY')) num_years
from enrollments e
inner join (select distinct sid from enrollments where exitcode = 'W21' ) x on e.sid = x.sid
group by e.student, e.sid
having count(distinct trunc(dated,'YYYY')) > 3

+----+---------------+--------------+-----------+
|    |    STUDENT    |     SID      | NUM_YEARS |
+----+---------------+--------------+-----------+
|  1 | Bart,Simpson  | 240022222222 |        10 |
|  2 | Homer,Simpson | 240000333333 |        10 |
+----+---------------+--------------+-----------+
```

see it working at http://rextester.com/VOGNJ58311

IF the exitcode W21 is the maximum value found in that column then you could achieve the result in a single pass of the data:

```
select
   e.student, e.sid, count(distinct trunc(dated,'YYYY')) num_years
from enrollments e
group by e.student, e.sid
having count(distinct trunc(dated,'YYYY')) > 3
And max(exitcode) = 'W21'
```